# How can I use a script to control another application?

Tags: automation

For example, I want to write a script to control and automate a sequence of steps in an application. How can I communicate between my script and the application I want to automate?

Comment: Is Windows, MAC, linux (KDE,GNOME,etc)?

Comment: The answer is operating specific and it helps to know which applications or types of applications you plan to automate.

Answer (score 1):

You need a macro recorder.  Google "Windows Macro Recorder" or "Mac Macro recorder" or KDE macro recorder.

Specific software like MS Excel, AutoCAD, and others have built in macro recorders.

In Windows if you are willing to spend a bunch of time learning how you can use **vba scripting** to access Windows API.

The software may have user accessible API making your job easier.

Comment: I've considered using macros but I was thinking of something faster and be able to run while I use the computer. I'm not sure what VBA scripting to access Windows API but I will try to look into that too.

Comment: @Kev I used Declare statements to access the API calls in the past.  I used it in VB6 and VBA is based on visual basic.